# openflow: preseve match metadata

Tags: openflow

I am writing an openflow rule that needs to preserve match metadata and pass it on to the next table. I used the following new metadata assignment

```
   newmetadata = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
   newmeatadataMask = 0x0
```

Will this do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES. It does preserve the metadata.